# Unable to import Dynamics CRM 2013 Custom Code Validation Tool solution

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

We're working on upgrading CRM 2011 to CRM 2013 and I'm trying to upload the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 Custom Code Validation Tool and the exact solution file name is CustomCodeValidationToolForMicrosoftDynamicsCRM201_2_0_0_1_managed.zip

It was downloaded from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30151

I'm using IE 11 on Windows 8.1 and as you may know CRM's Html forces the browser to use IE8 settings. The CRM website does not open in Chrome. The popup blocker is also disabled.

I have tried several times to import the solution but everytime it gets stuck on the "Import Customizations Dialog". There is no JavaScript error when the file is uploaded for import, the errors in the console appear when I click on the Import Solution button in the solution section.

Any ideas what could be done to fix it.

[image: F12 Window]

[image: Import Customizations Dialog CRM 2011]

Comment: Have you tried running IE in compatibility mode?

Comment: Yeah that was not the issue. One of the DLL's integrity was compromised actually and applying the rollup fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to install CRM 2011 Update rollup 17 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42672

Comment: I was having the same issue and installed CRM 2011 rollup 17 but that didn't make a difference. Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't have an exact solution but you could try running diagnostics tool when you try again and use tge trace log viewer to see if you can drill deeper into the problem.

https://crmdiagtool2011.codeplex.com

Comment: So I did and here is the exception I got: Crm Exception: Message: An error occurred while importing a Solution., ErrorCode: -2147188685

Comment: I checked the Application logs and here is what I got as a warning: Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.